# task.getResult() is throwing a java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using what is recommended by too many developers in order to retrieve the `Uri` of an image stored in the firebase storage , this my code :

```
final StorageReference filereference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    +"."+getFileExtension(imageUri));
uploadTask =filereference.putFile(imageUri);
uploadTask.continueWith(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot,Task<Uri>>() {
  @Override
  public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws 
  Exception {
             if(!task.isSuccessful()){
             throw task.getException();
             }
             return filereference.getDownloadUrl();

}

}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
 @Override
 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
 if(task.isSuccessful()){
 try{
     Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
     String mUri =downloadUri.toString();
     }catch (Exception e){
     Log.e("testingerror",e.toString());
     }
```

it throws me this error :
com.example.asus.fireapp E/stayinsh: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu cannot be cast to android.net.Uri

Comment: You are using an API that no longer exists.

Comment: Hi Doug, i am confused, i am literally using the google code from documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=0#get_a_download_url

Comment: @joghm upload task working or not ?

Comment: Upload is Working fine ,yes

Comment: Sorry, one of those other dups shows up every week.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what line of code the error is happening on.

Comment: BTW, the example you linked to is using continueWithTask, not continueWith.

Comment: @joghm Try Doug Stevenson's solution.

Comment: Solved,it was indeed continueWithTask,not continuewith. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if your using a FirebaseStorage Api of 10.0.1 or less
what i mean is
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'  or less

but if its greater use

```
StorageReference filepath=user_Image_ref.child(user_id+".jpg");
        filepath.putFile(resulturi).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    String getimageurl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                    databaseReference.child("PHOTO").setValue(getimageurl);


                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Register_activity.this,"errr",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                String getimageurl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                databaseReference.child("PHOTO").setValue(getimageurl);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be continueWithTask instead of continueWith

```
uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot,Task<Uri>>() {
  @Override
  public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws 
  Exception {
             if(!task.isSuccessful()){
             throw task.getException();
             }
             return filereference.getDownloadUrl();

}
```